# How to do Single Sign On for multiple MVC 4 web applications on IIS 7.5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7, iis-7.5, single-sign-on

I have 2 MVC 4 applications deployed on IIS 7.5. I would like to achieve a single sign on all of them. I have following web.config settings in both the applications -

```
  <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" enableCrossAppRedirects="true" path="/" name=".MVCAuthCookie" timeout="45"  defaultUrl="/" slidingExpiration="false" protection="All" cookieless="UseCookies" />
    </authentication>
<machineKey
      validationKey="C50B3C89CB21F4F1422FF158A5B42D0E8DB8CB5CDA1742572A487D9401E3400267682B202B746511891C1BAF47F8D25C07F6C39A104696DB51F17C529AD3CABE" 
      decryptionKey="8A9BE8FD67AF6979E7D20198CFEA50DD3D3799C77AF2B72F" 
      validation="SHA1" />
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
```

When I logged in in the first app and I browse second application in a separate tab, it still takes me to the login page for the second app. I can see in fiddler that the MVCAuthcookie is indeed getting passed with the get request for second application.

What am I missing here?

Comment: are both application under same domain ??

Comment: yes, they are on the same domain

Comment: may be this could be of some help http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/106439/Single-Sign-On-SSO-for-cross-domain-ASP-NET-applic

Comment: Yes, I did the same thing. I have 2 app on the same domain as explained in the first part of the article and I had used the same machine key for both the application. Still it does not work :(

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that I need to set compatibility mode for machinekey element to "Framework20SP2" as stated here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.machinekeysection.compatibilitymode.aspx which resolved the issue.