# Login from one web application and access another web application with same cookie value MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have 3 MVC Web applications: 1 for Managing user Logins and other 2 are separate applications for different tasks. If a user logined in application 1 he can able to access the 2 other applications with the same credential. I am using standard MVC authentication here. It works in localhost, but not working after hosting in IIS. The applications 2 and 3 are redirected to the login screen even if the user logined.

This is a image of the infrastructure:

[image: Check Image]

Comment: Might need to elaborate on "standard" authentication here.  Forms authentication?  Windows authentication?

Comment: Thank you for the response. It is Form authentication

Comment: It creates a cookie called ".ASPXAUTH". You could try capturing the contents of that cookie and forwarding it on. Not guaranteed to work though. You may need to consider OAuth based authentication.

Comment: I am changed other two application to Windows Auth mode in IIS then it works and Both .ASPXAUTH values are equal. But

Comment: See [Single sign on using same application but multiple domains ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11334301/), [How to do Single Sign On for multiple MVC 4 web applications on IIS 7.5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23627817/), and [C# ASP.NET Single Sign-On Implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14309354/).

Comment: Yah Thank you Boss

Answer (score 0):

The application share the same session, without modifying the cookie

You can make the following values same for each application

- Same Machine key
- Same Session storage i.e. OutProc
- same application name

Change configuration using web.config